# got stuck in mysql query. need help in positioning punctuation marks

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form name="a" id="a" method="post">
<textarea name="b" id="b"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="s" id="s" value="submit" />
</form>
```

here is the php part for this html form

```
if($_POST['s'] == "submit") {
    $v = $_POST['b'];
     $catupd = "insert into `tbl_safari_review`
      (`fld_revdesc`)  values ('$v')";
      mysql_query($catupd) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

When there is ' (apostrophe) in the description then it is giving error as follows:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''abc'')' at line 2

I tried so put quotes in many ways but no success.Please help me guys!!
Thank You.

Comment: please note i dont need any alternatives using PDO or mysqli!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$v = $_POST['b'];
```

change it to

```
$v = addslashes($_POST['b']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Never insert un sanitized user input to database.It will cause SQL injection. Try this

```
$catupd = sprintf("insert into `tbl_safari_review`
  (`fld_revdesc`)  values ('%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($v));
  mysql_query($catupd) or die(mysql_error());
```